# Accessing git server with specific url

Tags: gitolite

Can we add multiple git-web URL for a single git server. So that specific people can access their projects with their own URL'S?

When I have tired to search the results for above question, it is there like git daemon is used? If it is so? How it is useful?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you mean by a different URL? Do you mean different hostnames, or what?

Comment: Yes, I mean accessing a single git server with different hostname's.   For example: I have multiple projects in a single git server, If at all I give the gitweb url (Say x.domain.com), he/she can access the code of his project and also the other project as well. So in order to prevent that, can we give multiple hostnames(X.domain.com & x1.domain.com) for each one of them to access only their project.

Comment: Could you not dynamically display different repos to different users? If you enable http authentication, you'll know the userid. I think that https://git-scm.com/docs/gitweb.conf , the `$export_auth_hook` could look at the `$REMOTE_USER` environment variable to figure out what repos a user has access to.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier, especially with a Git repository hosting server managed by Gitolite, to:

- access the same server

And:

- different repositories (one per user)
- OR different branches (one per user) within the same repository.

As to that last option, you can read "[Gitolite: Personal branches](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/user/#personal-branches)":

> "personal" branches are great for environments where developers need to share work but can't directly pull from each other (usually due to either a networking or authentication related reason, both common in corporate setups).